# How to "toggle" the date format of git-log? How to display both relative and absolute dates simultaneously in the same git log?

Tags: git, date, git-log

My current default git log line runs as follows:

```
git log --graph --date=relative --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s' --abbrev-commit -7
```

Sometimes, however, I'd prefer an absolute date/time format, rather than relative, so I tried: `--date=default` and `--date=local` instead of `--date=relative` and even left `--date=..` out altogether: the result was unchanged. Possibly it has to do with ["log.date config variable sets a default value for log command's --date option."](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-log), I don't know. Possibly I'd need to restart the terminal (but if that were the case I'd be a tad disappointed...).

In short, I'd like to "toggle" the date, and morever even be able to use both date formats in one instance of git log.

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to see author information in your log. They are usually the same but not always. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18750808/761771

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset %Cgreen(**%cr**)%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s'

`%cr` in a format string means relative committer date.

From `git help log`;

- `%cd`: committer date
- `%cD`: committer date, RFC2822 style
- `%cr`: committer date, relative
- `%ct`: committer date, UNIX timestamp
- `%ci`: committer date, ISO 8601 format

Changing the format to for example `%ci` will show the date in absolute format.

Comment: Thanks! and regarding my second question, this (based on your comments) works and answers it: `git log --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %Cblue(%cd)%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s'`