# What flow causes Github commits that are "authored" by one user but "committed" by another?

Tags: github, commit, git-commit

For example, [this commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/690a2b1fa2c8a7dba0be84dfc052d86b864bedc3) is claimed to be authored by *mattcaswell* and committed by *richsalz*

[image]

What usage flow could have caused this? Suppose I want a commit which is authored by someone else and committed by me to appear in a repo where I'm a contributor - how would I have that?

Answer (score 55):

Git distinguishes between authors and committers (see [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18750808/3906760)). Authors are the people who wrote a specific piece of code - committers are the people who put these changes into the git "history".

Normally both are the same (and doesn't change on merging, cloning, pushing or pulling).

Causing the two to point to different people can happen on [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), editing a commit (e.g. [amending](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)), doing a commit on behalf of someone else (e.g.  by specifying [--author](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)), applying patches ([git am](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html)), squashing (e.g., on [merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) or [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)), or [cherry-picking](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Answer (score 12):

Since March 2019 (5 years after the OP's question), there is another scenario where a commit authored by one person, and committed by another, especially in the context of the [organization `github.com/openssl`](https://github.com/openssl) used in the question.

> ### Creating a commit on behalf of an organization
>
> Developers can indicate their intent to contribute to a project on behalf of an organization.
>   This can help minimize confusion over ownership, for example, when contributing to a third-party project on behalf of your employer.
>
> For a given commit to be associated with an organization:
>
> - The committer must add an `On-behalf-of` commit trailer to the commit, in the form of: On-behalf-of: `@ORG <ORG CONTACT EMAIL>`,
> - The committer must be a member of the organization,
> - The commit must be committed with an email in the organization’s verified domain, and
> - The commit must be signed.
>
> Support for the `On-behalf-of` commit trailer is currently in public beta.
>   For more information, see [creating a commit on behalf of an organization](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-commit-on-behalf-of-an-organization).

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/write-commit-message-on-behalf-of-trailer.png]