# When actually the commit happened

Tags: github, timeline

When I go to the [page](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8996/commits/lineage-15.1) as below screen shot, the page show "Jaegeuk Kim authored and bgcngm committed 18 days ago" and the "Commits on Jun 4, 2018".

But I go to the page of bgcngm's commit [history page](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8996/commits?author=bgcngm), I did not find this commit record.

My question is how this happened, and what happened at Jun 4 and 18 days ago, and how to do it.

Jaegeuk Kim authored and bgcngm committed 18 days ago:
[image: Jaegeuk Kim authored and bgcngm committed 18 days ago]

Comment: This answer explains the difference between an author and a committer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25327781/866021

Comment: Thanks Adil, but look like bgcngm has not ever commit the patch when i check his activity page.

Comment: After check the gerrit [link](https://review.lineageos.org/#/c/LineageOS/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8996/+/216864/), it truly bgcngm commit at 4 Jun and Jaegeuk Kim changed the code at 18 days ago.
But I still can't figure out how to make one commit like this.