# How to get last commit date inside a folder/directory in github repo?

Tags: git, github, github-api

For example: I want to get a last commit date in here - `https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/master/dev-tools/pmd`

With this I can get into pmd folder - `https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/contents/dev-tools/pmd`

But this doesn't have any data about the dates. I tried `https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/contents/dev-tools/pmd/commits` and this returns me 'not found' message.

Tried the git url with sha - `https://api.github.com/repos/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/git/blobs/58788337ae94dbeaac72a0901d778a629460c992` but even this doesn't return any helpful info.

How to get the date of the commit inside a folder using github-api?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### New answer using the GitHub API:

Request the [commits that touched the subdirectory](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits`, passing in the `path` argument that specifies the subdirectory in question:

> `path`: string, Only commits containing this file path will be returned.

The response will be zero or more commits. Take the latest and look at its `commit/author/date` or `commit/committer/date`, depending on which you're looking for:

```
[
  {
    ...,
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        ...,
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        ...,
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      ...,
    },
  },
]
```

### Original answer using a local copy:

Try `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%cd path/to/directory`. This will give you the *committer date* of the most recent commit in that directory.

You can also use [these other date formats](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

- `%cD`: committer date, RFC2822 style
- `%cr`: committer date, relative
- `%ct`: committer date, UNIX timestamp
- `%ci`: committer date, ISO 8601 format
- `%ad`: author date (format respects --date= option)
- `%aD`: author date, RFC2822 style
- `%ar`: author date, relative
- `%at`: author date, UNIX timestamp
- `%ai`: author date, ISO 8601 format

Comment: Awesome, I tried it on my example and got the output. But any idea why is it showing 2 different dates i.e. in author it shows 2014-03-12 and in committer it's 2014-03-13?

Comment: What is the difference between author and committer?

Comment: @tech_human, often there is no difference. But the person who wrote the code is the author, and the person who most recently committed it is the committer. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18754896/354577), which references [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html) in Pro Git, for more detail. I'm pretty sure that these can have different dates but the same author if, e.g., the author rebased the commit.

Comment: Basically, for local, this boils down to using the additional flag `-n 1` and entering in the directory path as a position argument after `git log`. i.e. `git log -n 1 <PATH>`.