# How to apply a patch using git without configuration

Tags: git, configuration, patch

I have written some instructions that also use git to apply some patches.
The instructions are intended to be put into the console and be done with it.
Like this:

```
git am bar.patch
git am foo.patch
```

But git is now asking for the users name/email:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@user-VirtualBox.(none)')
You need to set your committer info first
```

This does not seem to be needed, as only the author of the the patches appear in the git log, but not the one who applied them. Is there a way to ignore configuration?

edit: typos

Comment: All commits have both an author and committer, there is no way around that. What's wrong with just configuring the user name/email once and being done with it ?

Comment: The problem is that people copy&paste the commands and do not see that git fails to apply the patches (because git is not configured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754896/6309)"

When you apply a patch, you are the committer. So Git needs to know who "you" are.

Regarding [git am](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), I would recommend considering to use the `--committer-date-is-author-date` if you want the date associated with those commits created by those patch to be the same as the date recorded in said patches.

Comment: The patch is applied to a local repository and ultimately thrown away. I tried to use git am --author "New Author Name <email@address.com>" foo.patch, but git does not accept this. Maybe a non-git patch is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Git checks the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, and `EMAIL` environmental variables. This works:

```sh
EMAIL=root@localhost git am foo.patch
```