# Is it possible to set committer to same person who is defined in patch as author when using git am?

Tags: git, git-patch

Is it possible to set committer to same person who is defined as author in patch when applying patch with `git am` command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that.

Simply use:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='committer name' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='commiter@email.com' git commit -m "message"
```

In case you are amending a commit, use

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='committer name' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='commiter@email.com' git commit --amend
```

You can have a look at [Difference between author and committer in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23108169/1860929) to understand more about committer and author in git.

Comment: Where should i put it? Commits are created with `git am`, i do not create them manually when apply patch