# Time next to some entries less than commit date?

Tags: github

Looking at the attached pic the last commit was 5 days ago, however the first 2 lines show changes 39 mins ago.

https://github.com/popcornmix/xbmc/tree/newclock5

If I click on the change description for the first line then it shows the commit was 3 year ago.

What am I missing here? Am I not understanding the whole commit/date/time thing?

Would appreciate it if someone explained this. I would think the latest commit should then show 39 mins ago?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On git are two types of dates: `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` (when you made the original commit) and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` (when patch was applied).

In your example changes was commited 3 years ago but was applied later.

You could read more about author and commiter differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754896/1349549