# IDEA: IntelliJ/PyCharm not using my .gitconfig data

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have fresh install of IDEA InteliJ and PyCharm installed with git support enabled. However, when I try to `Ctrl+K` to commit the author field is empty. Moreover, the `Ctrl+Space` says "No Suggestion".

I have my `~/.gitconfig` generated properly by PyCharm is not using its data.

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

How to make PyCharm to use the data from regular `.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 1):

The author field is only supposed to be filled in if the one who wrote the code is different from the commiter. See more about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754896/1264116)

So if you don't explicitly fill in another author in IntelliJ, the author will be the same as the commiter, which is retrieved from the git config. You can't really see what this is in the "Commit Changes" window, except if you hover your mouse over the "Sign-off commit" checkbox.

Comment: "hover your mouse over the "Sign-off commit" checkbox [to see the configured commit user]" was really useful!