# Git: how to commit as someone else?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a freelance project. The client (let's call him **foobar**) asked me to upload the code using his github account (my work PC runs 64-bit Windows 10, I have git 2.15.0) installed.

So I did these steps.

1. Go to Credential Manager -> Windows Credential -> Generic Credentials. Removed my Github account
2. On the source code directory, performed the standard procedure:

   ```
   git init
   git add *
   git commit -m "first message"
   git remote add origin https://github.com/foobar/supersecretproject.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

A Github credential dialog appeared. Entered his credential.

Wait for a while, and yes the code was commited to Github. Opended the Github page, and strangely the commiter shown was me, not **foobar**. Strange. How to fix this? I want to commit as **foobar**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to change config settings for just one repo. You can try this procedure:

1) On the terminal, change the current working directory to the local repository where you want to configure the name and email that is associated with your Git commits.

```
2) $ git config user.name "Elon Musk". 

3) $ git config user.email "elonmusk@tesla.com"
```

3) Confirm that you have set the Git username and email correctly:

```
 $ git config user.name

> Elon Musk

 $ git config user.email

> elonmusk@tesla.com
```

It's done!:)

Hope this might help!

Comment: This sets the user local-only (tied with current repository), notice there is NOT used '--global' flag, so the global account will remain as it was. Adding this comment as I didn't notice the difference :)

Answer (score 19):

If you only want to create a single commit on behalf of someone else and do not want to edit your config, you can also specify the `--author` argument instead:

```sh
git commit --author "Elon Musk <elonmusk@tesla.com>"
```

This will only set the *author* metadata of the commit, not the committer metadata about yourself. However, I would even consider this idiomatic as while the correct authorship is maintained, tracing the back the commit to you in case of any troubles is still possible.

Found [here](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/4343/committing-on-behalf-of-someone-else).

Comment: Worth checking, difference between Author and Committer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git

Answer (score 1):

You also need to configure your name and email for git:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```