# Git author with a star after their name

Tags: git, intellij-idea

PersonA do a commit and PersonB's name with a star show in the commit history  in IntelliJ IDEA **Version Control** tab.

why commit **User** name changed?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It indicates a commit where the author and committer are different.

From the [**Push changes to a remote repository** section of **Commit and push changes** in the IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#push):

> If the author of a commit is different from the current user, this
>   commit is marked with an asterisk.

Comment: how can this happen? imo, the author and committer is the same person.

Comment: If you look at the log information the commit, it may provide more insight. For discussion regarding the difference between the two, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git.

Comment: This would happen when Some Person who is not you, rebases the branch. In that case the author would be you, but the committer would be Some Person.

You can see both by running `git cat-file commit <your-commit-hash>`