# Change commit user between git remotes

Tags: git

I have outsourced some tasks to other users. Made a copy of the main repository (work) to a different remote (private). The coworker committed changes to the private remote and I would like to push these commits to the work remote with my user. Is there built-in way for this in git or some workarounds?

Comment: Maybe rebase them or just merge with squash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do interactive rebase with edit :)

**Before** you push (probably you want to hide this information ;)) please **verify** [author & commiter in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git) to not get into trouble ;)

Please also consider remember that you can [force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push) if you did mistake.

Example on 2 commits:

```
* cd6b0ac (HEAD -> master) Fix test file
* e3e822e Add test file
```

Long version (`git log`)

```
commit cd6b0ac5a33283743f524463d0e78a2d3e335e4d (HEAD -> master)
Author: Bob <bob@git.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 29 10:26:12 2018 +0000

    Fix test file

commit e3e822e89397fdadbd1c6e1ac6710d96590d92c6
Author: Bob <bob@git.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 29 10:25:53 2018 +0000

    Add test file
```

Now I will rebase with edit.
`git rebase -i e3e822e89397fdadbd1c6e1ac6710d96590d92c6`

In console now I will see:

```
pick cd6b0ac Fix test file

# Rebase e3e822e..cd6b0ac onto e3e822e (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
... (more I don't want paste)
```

So for this commit I pick `e` and save->quit.

```
e cd6b0ac Fix test file
```

So now your working tree will be checkout to that commit.
Now you need to do 2 steps:

1. `git commit --amend --author="Dawid <dawid@git.com>"`
2. `git rebase --continue` go to next commit you picked to edit or finish rebase.

Now `git log` to verify

```
commit ec0949d075626ed9416d74c02bcbed721b8be2fe (HEAD)
Author: Dawid <dawid@git.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 29 10:26:12 2018 +0000

    Fix test file

commit e3e822e89397fdadbd1c6e1ac6710d96590d92c6
Author: Bob <bob@git.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 29 10:25:53 2018 +0000

    Add test file
```

If you want to pick more commits to rebase you can write such thing: `git rebase -i HEAD^^` (pick last 2 commits)

---

To verify use [`git log --pretty=full`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

```
commit ec0949d075626ed9416d74c02bcbed721b8be2fe (HEAD)
Author: Dawid <dawid@git.com>
Commit: Dawid <dawid@git.com>

    Fix test file

commit e3e822e89397fdadbd1c6e1ac6710d96590d92c6
Author: Bob <bob@git.com>
Commit: Bob <bob@git.com>

    Add test file
```

Read about [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

[Other simlar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-one-specific-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Clone your coworker repo locally and execute like in the following command:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Super Man"; export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="man@superfamily.org"'
```

(put the desirable user name and mail in place of the fictional character ones)

**Warning: this will rebase the tree and all commit ids will change**

Now you can push it.

See also [Changing author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) on GitHub