# Git rebase commits not repeatable

Tags: git, rebase

When I have 2 branches pointing at the same commit, and then rebase them both onto the same new base commit, why do the rebased branches diverge?

I expected that they'd replay in the same way, and end up pointing at the same new commit.

```
touch a; touch b; touch c
git add a
git commit -m 'a'
git add b
git commit -m 'b'
git checkout -b branch-01 HEAD^
git add c
git commit -m 'c'
git checkout -b branch-02
git rebase master branch-01
git rebase master branch-02
git log --all --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why the Branches Diverged

Among the metadata used to calculate the hash for a git commit, not only is there an `Author` and an `AuthorDate`; there is also a `Committer` and a `CommitterDate`. This can be seen by running e.g.

```
git show --pretty=fuller branch-01 branch-02
```

Each `rebase` (or `cherry-pick`) command updates the committer date in the new commit(s) according to the current time. Since the two rebases in the question were performed at different times, their `CommitterDate`s differ, thus their metadata differ, thus their commit hashes differ.

## How To Move Branches/Tags Together

[torek correctly notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877839/git-rebase-commits-not-repeatable/56877985#56877985) that

> if you want to move *two or more* names while copying some chain of commits, you'll be OK using `git rebase` to move the first name, but you will have to do something else—such as run `git branch -f`—to move the remaining names, so that they point to the commit copies made during the one rebase.

## About Author vs Committer

From [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git/18754896#18754896):

> The author is the person who originally wrote the code. The committer, on the other hand, is assumed to be the person who committed the code on behalf of the original author. This is important in Git because Git allows you to rewrite history, or apply patches on behalf of another person. The [**FREE** online **Pro Git** book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html) explains it like this:
>
> > You may be wondering what the difference is between *author* and *committer*. The *author* is the person who originally wrote the patch, whereas the *committer* is the person who last applied the patch. So, if you send in a patch to a project and one of the core members applies the patch, both of you get credit — you as the author and the core member as the committer.

Answer (score 3):

To explain what happened, try this as an experiment:

```
$ git checkout -b exp1 master
<modify some file; git add; all the usual stuff here>
$ git commit -m commit-on-exp1
```

At this point you have an experimental branch named `exp1` with one commit that's not on `master`:

```
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C1   <-- exp1
```

Now we'll make an `exp2` branch pointing to commit `B`, and copy commit `C1` to a new commit `C2` on branch `exp2`:

```
$ git checkout -b exp2 master
$ git cherry-pick exp1
```

The result is:

```
          C2   <-- exp2
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C1   <-- exp1
```

Now let's repeat with `exp3`, creating it so that it points to commit `B` and then copying `exp1` again:

```
$ git checkout -b exp3 master
$ git cherry-pick exp1
```

Do you expect `exp3` to point to commit `C2`?  If so, why?  Why did `exp2` point to `C2` rather than to `C1` like `exp1`?

The issue here is that commits `C1` and `C2` (and now `C3` on `exp3`) are *not* bit-for-bit identical.  It's true they have the same *snapshot*, the same *author*, the same *log message*, and even the same parent (all three have `B` as their one parent).  But all three have different *committer date-and-time-stamps*, so they are different commits.  (Use `git show --pretty=fuller` to show both date-and-time-stamps.  Cherry-pick, and hence rebase too, copies the original author information including date-and-time, but because it's a new commit, uses the current date-and-time for the committer timestamp.)

---

When you use `git rebase`, in general, you have Git copy commits, as if by cherry-pick.  At the end of the copying, Git then moves the *branch name* so that it points to the last copied commit:

```
...--A--B   <-- mainline
      \
       C--D--E   <-- sidebranch
```

becomes:

```
          C'-D'-E'  <-- sidebranch
         /
...--A--B   <-- mainline
      \
       C--D--E
```

Here `C'` is the copy of `C` that's changed to use `B` as its parent (and perhaps has a different source snapshot than `C`), `D'` is the copy of `D`, and `E'` is the copy of `E`.  There was only one name pointing to `E`; that name is now moved, so there is *no* name pointing to `E`.

But if you have *two* names pointing to `E` originally, *one* of those two names still points to `E`:

```
          C'-D'-E'  <-- sidebranch
         /
...--A--B   <-- mainline
      \
       C--D--E   <-- other-side-branch
```

If you ask Git to copy `C-D-E` again, it does that—but the new copies are not `C'-D'-E'` because they have new date-and-time stamps.  So you end up with what you saw.

Hence, if you want to move *two or more* names while copying some chain of commits, you'll be OK using `git rebase` to move the first name, but you will have to do something else—such as run `git branch -f`—to move the remaining names, so that they point to the commit copies made during the one rebase.

(I've always wanted to have a fancier version of `git rebase` that can do this automatically, but it's clearly a hard problem in general.)

Comment: `all three have different date-and-time-stamps, so they are different commits.` I think this is the crux of your explanation, and it would make sense, but `git log` shows me that both rebased commits have the same timestamp.

Comment: Also, the only differences in the outputs from `git show` on the 2 rebased commits are the commit IDs and the branch names.

Comment: Use `git show --pretty=fuller` so that you see *both* time stamps. There must be some difference: different parent, or different author, committer, tree, or log message. If there is no difference at all, the commit is literally the same commit and thus has the same hash ID and there aren't two separate commits.

Comment: Ah! `git show --pretty=fuller` shows that the the `AuthorDate`s are the same, but the `CommitDate`s differ. That explains it. Could you update your answer to make this more explicit?

Comment: Also, I'd rather see just about all of the `cherry-pick` stuff in your answer go away, as IMO it just adds clutter, and I already understood that you can use it to the same effect as a `rebase`. (i.e. My answer to your questions, "Do you expect exp3 to point to commit C2? If so, why?" was yes, because I was not aware of any metadata to create the difference.)

Comment: I don't have time right now for a fancier rewrite, and cherry-pick (which rebase uses internally) is what copies the author date stamp, so I'll just note that it's the committer date stamp here...

Comment: Good edits, thanks for those. Any additional updates you make need not be immediate. But note I was asking for simpler, not "fancier". What I mean is IMO, this would be better if you got rid of *everything* before the sentence beginning "The issue here...". I think your new addition makes the point.