# Where do old dated commits come from in AOSP?

Tags: android, git

I'm following the commits to master branch of Messaging app in AOSP. Sometimes I see very old dated commits appear at the top in its logs:
[image: Messaging app master branch commits]
How do I find where these commits come from? If they're on a separate branch, how do I find that branch and the initial original commit into the repository?

Answer (score 0):

That is the latest commit on `master`. The date is when the author made the change, but it was [committed recently](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/+/c12077e4fb3fa1d4fa167d0fd754700791bbf0fd) (2 days ago).

The author and committer [need not be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18750808/5987698).

Comment: I'm not asking why the author and commiter are different... these are bug fixes from 4-5 years ago, and I only could see now. Where are such fixes are kept? I think I should be able to find them since this is an open source project, right?

Comment: @Tekins, Android vendors completely out of the idea of OSS and putting back changes. So, it may have been kept in many places, starting from internal repository of a vendor.