# Change who commited in Github?

Tags: git, github

I see this message in Github:

```
john doe authored and My Name committed 4 minutes ago
```

Where does Github pickup `My Name` from? How can I remove it or change it to `john doe`?

I know that I can change the author with

```
git rebase -r --root --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author"
```

But I don't know how to change the name of the person who commited.

Comment: Have you tried ```git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: Relevant background: [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18750808/157957)

Comment: of course, are you sure you changed windows "credential manager" setting

Comment: The suggestion by @SergedeGossondeVarennes worked